# How to reduce the height and width of particular row of panel inside tablelayoutpanel?

Tags: c#, winforms, panel, tablelayoutpanel

I am using one

```
tablelayoutpanel
```

in which i have added one panel, Now i want to get that panel at run time and want to reduce the width of panel by half and then add another panel with the same size.

In simple words i want to make two square of panel inside that tablelayoutpanel row.

No. of column = 1,No. of rows = 2

```
Need : Add multiple controls with same size inside any row of the 
tablelayoutpanel.
```

Answer (score 0):

Its is very simple to use [`TableLayoutPanel`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel.aspx) at run-time (also called *in code behind*). Basically repeating msdn (in simpler words I hope):

- use `ColumnCount`/`ColumnStyles` and `RowCount`/`RowStyles` to setup `TableLayoutPanel` itself (as you do it in the form designer);
- use methods `SetColumn(control, column)` and `SetRow(control, row)` to put some existing `control` into specific *cell*;
- use methods `GetColumn`/`GetRow` to check where some control is located;
- use method `GetControlFromPosition(column, row)` to get which control is located in given *cell*.

Feel free to ask questions in comments if something is not clear so we can go through .

Comment: Actually i want to add multiple panels inside one tablelayoutPanel with same height and width . You can think about chess board like structure.

Comment: Chess board? You can set 8 rows and 8 columns (for each row/column add new style with `SizeType.Percent` and same value) -> this will cause `TableLayoutPanel` to automatically size all cells similarly. Then for each cell create `Panel` with `Dock=DockStyle.Fill`. If you then change visual appearance of each even panel -> you will have kind of chess board.

Comment: One more thing , how can i add multiple columns in only a single row?

Comment: i mean if rowIndex = 2 , then column should be seperated into two equal parts in only that particular row?

Comment: The magic of *equal parts* is done by `SizeType.Percent` and docking. If all columns/rows have style `Percent` and same value - each cell with/height will be equal. By using `DockSyle.Fill` you tell control to occupy exactly cell size. If you want to have different number of columns in specific row, then this is usually done as following: `ColumnCount` is set to biggest number and in that row some of cells have `ColumnSpan` set (means what item occupy more than one column).

Comment: Do you have any live example or any Demo then please tell .